# How to make responsive UI using css?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

How can I make the following UI responsive using `css`.

```
 <Text className="w-100 mt-0 align-self-center">
     Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum<span>{'$200'}</span>
    </Text>                                                                                         

    <Text className="w-100 mt-0 align-self-center">
    Lorem ipsum<span>{'$100'}</span>Lorem ipsum
    </Text>

    <Text className="w-100 mt-0 align-self-center">
     {"Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"}
     <Button
      className="link-button"
      variant={VARIANTS.LINK}
      >
     <ButtonText>{'here'}</ButtonText>
     </Button>
     </Text>
```

The styles for `Text` and `Button` is as follows

```
const Text = styled.div`
  font-family: ${(props) => props.theme.font.base};
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.text.secondary};
  a,
  button {
    text-decoration: underline currentColor;
    &:hover:not(:disabled) {
      text-decoration-color: transparent;
    }
  }
  span {
    font-weight: 600;
    white-space: nowrap;
    @media screen and (max-width: ${breakpoints.desktop}px) and (min-width: ${breakpoints.laptopL}px) {
      margin-top: 25px !important;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: ${breakpoints.tablet}px) {
      margin-top: 25px !important;
    }
  }
`;
```

Currently, this is what I am getting in responsive, the UI is breaking. How can I rewrite the styles to work in a responsive view? Any help is really appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Don't waste your time, Use any design framework like Bootstrap, it is free.

Comment: If I am using bootstrap then how can I rewrite this styles?? @Zaid

Comment: Add your own `style.css` file after bootstrap in this way you can overwrite any rule written in BS. For example, in your file, you can write `.container{width:1000px;}` you don't need to put `!important` in your style. Only one rule code compiles from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is a good solution for making a responsive UI.

Note: You can use bootstrap classes directly in HTML file also.

```css
.align {
  color: #958989;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.responsive {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

span,
a {
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="align">
  <div class="w-100 mt-1 responsive">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <span>$ 200</span>
  </div>

  <div class="w-100 mt-1 responsive">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <span>$ 100</span>
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div class="w-100 mt-1 responsive">
    <span> Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</span>
    <a class="link-button"> here </a>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me.! @ Akshita Tyagi